# Center multiple divs in viewport

Tags: css

I want to line up 5 divs in one row, as shown below: [image]. To do this, I used `display:inline-block`, however, the final result shows three divs skewed to one side of the page.

```js
  function toggleButton() { 
 $('.below').toggle();
  return false;
 }

  function toggleEnd() { 
 $('.under').toggle();
  return false;
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // get box count
  var count = 0;
  var checked = 0;
  function countBoxes() { 
    count = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
    console.log(count);
  }
  
  countBoxes();
  $(":checkbox").click(countBoxes);
  
  // count checks
  
  function countChecked() {
    checked = $("input:checked").length;
    
    var percentage = parseInt(((checked / count) * 100),10);
    $(".progressbar-bar").progressbar({
            value: percentage
        });
    $(".progressbar-label").text(percentage + "%");
  }
  
  countChecked();
  $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color:black;
 padding:20px;
}

*{
 user-select: none; 
}

.accordion{
 background-color:#F2F2F2;
 border-left: 10px #B8E8E5 solid;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:auto;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 transition:0.3s ease;
 display:inline-block;
 padding-right
 
}

.accordion:hover{
 background-color:lightgray;
 transition:0.3s ease;
}

.below{
 display: none;
 transition:0.5s ease;
}

.header{
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}


.progressbar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px; 
}

.progressbar-bar { 
  height: 25px;
margin: 10px 0;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.progressbar-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ui-progressbar-value { 
 background: lightblue
}

.under{
 display:none;
}

.clicknotHere{
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 class = "header">Algebra 2</h1>
<br>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>



<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>


<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of ways you could do this. I would probably recommend wrapping a div around the accordions with a `display: flex;` property and aligning them with flexbox. Probably the easiest to control. You could also wrap a div around them and use `margin: 0 auto;` which would most likely do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fully working for you :) including the spaces between them and the correct sides. I added a `width` in the `.accordion` and `border-right` to make the border match on each side. Hope this helps out! :)

```js
  function toggleButton() { 
 $('.below').toggle();
  return false;
 }

  function toggleEnd() { 
 $('.under').toggle();
  return false;
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // get box count
  var count = 0;
  var checked = 0;
  function countBoxes() { 
    count = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
    console.log(count);
  }
  
  countBoxes();
  $(":checkbox").click(countBoxes);
  
  // count checks
  
  function countChecked() {
    checked = $("input:checked").length;
    
    var percentage = parseInt(((checked / count) * 100),10);
    $(".progressbar-bar").progressbar({
            value: percentage
        });
    $(".progressbar-label").text(percentage + "%");
  }
  
  countChecked();
  $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color:black;
 padding:20px;
}

*{
 user-select: none; 
}

.accordion{
 background-color:#F2F2F2;
 border-left: 10px #B8E8E5 solid;
    border-right: 10px #B8E8E5 solid;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:auto;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 transition:0.3s ease;
 display:inline-block;
 width:17%;
}

.accordion:hover{
 background-color:lightgray;
 transition:0.3s ease;
}

.below{
 display: none;
 transition:0.5s ease;
}

.header{
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}


.progressbar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px; 
}

.progressbar-bar { 
  height: 25px;
margin: 10px 0;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.progressbar-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ui-progressbar-value { 
 background: lightblue
}

.under{
 display:none;
}

.clicknotHere{
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 class = "header">Algebra 2</h1>
<br>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>



<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>


<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: My only question is why is there so much blank space to the right? I checked, and I didn't add any margins (I even removed the body padding)

Comment: @BigCoder101 updated it for you, added a border-right

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox:

```js
  function toggleButton() { 
 $('.below').toggle();
  return false;
 }

  function toggleEnd() { 
 $('.under').toggle();
  return false;
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  // get box count
  var count = 0;
  var checked = 0;
  function countBoxes() { 
    count = $("input[type='checkbox']").length;
    console.log(count);
  }
  
  countBoxes();
  $(":checkbox").click(countBoxes);
  
  // count checks
  
  function countChecked() {
    checked = $("input:checked").length;
    
    var percentage = parseInt(((checked / count) * 100),10);
    $(".progressbar-bar").progressbar({
            value: percentage
        });
    $(".progressbar-label").text(percentage + "%");
  }
  
  countChecked();
  $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color:black;
 padding:20px;
}

*{
 user-select: none; 
}

.flex-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}
.accordion{
 background-color:#F2F2F2;
 border-left: 10px #B8E8E5 solid;
 margin:auto;
 overflow:auto;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
 transition:0.3s ease;
 display:inline-block;
 padding-right
 
}

.accordion:hover{
 background-color:lightgray;
 transition:0.3s ease;
}

.below{
 display: none;
 transition:0.5s ease;
}

.header{
 margin:auto;
 text-align:center;
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}


.progressbar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px; 
}

.progressbar-bar { 
  height: 25px;
margin: 10px 0;
border-radius: 0px;
}

.progressbar-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.ui-progressbar-value { 
 background: lightblue
}

.under{
 display:none;
}

.clicknotHere{
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 class = "header">Algebra 2</h1>
<br>

<div class="flex-container">

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>



<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>


<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

<!--Container-->
<div class = "accordion">
 <p class = "clickHere" onclick="toggleButton()">
 Unit 1 - Relations and Linear Functions
 </p>

<!--Progress bar-->
<div class="progressbar-container">
  <div class="progressbar-bar"></div>
  <div class="progressbar-label"></div>
</div>

<!--Excerise Names-->
<div class = "below">
 <ul class="topics">
    <li><input type="checkbox">Relations and Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Domain and Range</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Graphing Abs. Val. Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Piecewise Functions Day 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Comparing Two Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One to One Functions</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Two Equations</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Solving Inequalites</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Systems of Three Equations w/Elimination</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Linear Regression</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Arithmetics Sequences Recursion</li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>

</div>
```